# How can I test for a null byte?

Tags: bytecode

; Windows 7
; emacs 29.1

; Is there a way to tell emacs to test for a null without entering a null in elisp?

; Putting a null anywhere in my elisp produces "Error: End of file during parsing".

; Variations of this won't compile:

(if (looking-at "X")     ;"X" is a null, i.e. CTRL-@ (CTRL-SHIFT-2).

```
                     ;I didn't want to insert a null in this post.
```

(message "%s" "match")
(message "%s" "not match")
)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: How are you trying to insert a null character/byte? Show your code, please, and format it using 3 backquotes before and after it.

Comment: ```
; Here is my elisp, with a null byte in the looking-at
; I use CTRL-Q CTRL-@ to insert the null
;(The forum software has replaced my null with "\0".)

(if (looking-at "\0") 

  (message "%s" "match")

  (message "%s" "not match")
)
```

Comment: As it happens (per the referenced docs), the forum software is correct.

Comment: Put such info in the *question*, not in a comment. Put all info relevant to your question in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time, and they're not searchable.

Answer (score 2):

See the elisp manual:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)General Escape Syntax`
- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Non-ASCII in Strings`

Per those docs, the null character syntax is `?\000` or just `?\0`, and therefore you can include a null character in string syntax as `"\000"` or just `"\0"`.

Comment: A good thought, but I haven't figured out how to get a null byte into looking-at's regular expression.

Comment: If you'd looked at that documentation you'd already know (see the final paragraph).

Comment: I've updated the answer with those details from the manual... but it was all there (and cross-linked) from the node I gave you initially.  Please do read the docs that people point you to.